# VB.net app Microsoft .NET framework error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hope you guys can help!

I have a vb.net application running on our network which connects to SQL Server. My application has a login screen which I am able to successfully login, which then should load another form, but I get an error message (see below).

However the application was working normally, until I changed the TCP/IP properties in SQL configuration manager. I'm sure I restored those changes, but it still doesn't work.

I can provide more information if need be.

Your help would be greatly appreciated! Have a nice weekend!

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond.)

Comment: What *exactly* did you change? You've broken connectivity, but there are too many posisble ways to enumerate.

Comment: you probable disabled tcp/ip and named pipes protocol in configuration manager. Enable them again and restart the sql server browser service

Comment: @Richard I think I must have. I only changed the TCP dynamic ports for IPALL for testing, but I have reverted the changes and now my application is not working.

Comment: @GuidoG TCP/IP and Named Pipes are both enabled. I have tried restarting the services, but  still no luck.

Comment: without knowing what you had changed we can only guess

Comment: @GuidoG I was only changing the TCP/IP /TCP ports properties in sql manager by removing adding different values. I then reverted those changing thinking it will fix the problem.

Comment: have you restarted sql server also

Comment: It does however manage to log on through pass the login screen which the login detail is captured from the SQL database, which means it can connect to the database table, but not the other tables.

Comment: @GuidoG Restarted the SQL server services many times.

Comment: The error message is too broad.  There's too many possibilities for what's going wrong when the error is "Unknown networking error" and that's exactly what this is.  You're going to have to manually troubleshoot the connection.  Try connecting to the SQL server from a different system.  Try restarting the SQL server.  Try connecting from PowerShell from the same computer and firing off some queries to relevant tables.  You're going to have to do some manual legwork to narrow down where the error is.

Comment: try disabling the firewall on both your pc and on the server

Comment: @ Bacon Bits I will try to connect to it using another machine once i get back to work on Monday. Messing with the TCP/IP wasn't a good idea!

Comment: @ GuidoG Tried that but still no luck. I'm just wondering could this have anything to do with the settings in the registry.

Comment: will providing the TCp/IP properties image to you guys be of any help?

Comment: open cmd in one of your client machines and write this command: `telnet n.n.n.n xxx` when x.x.x.x is the ip of your sql server and xxx is the port number, what is the result?

Comment: @ jonathana I only get a blank cmd prompt when i type telnet ip port

Comment: @ jonathana when I type telnet x.x.x.x i get the message connecting to x.x.x.x could not open the connection to the host on port 23 connection failed.

Comment: there is no way the sql server is opened to port 23 (telnet port) what is the port number your sql server is listening? (most networks use 1433)

Comment: and you did not entered your port number to the command, you should telnet to the port number the server is listening, it should be like  that                          `telnet 192.168.15.15 1433`  for example

Comment: @ jonathana I typed telnet 192.168.0.3 1433 into the cmd and it just came up with a blank cmd prompt....not sure why that is. My tcp port is set to 1433.

Comment: @anthony that is good, it means that clients have access to the server on port 1433. so the problem is probably with server configuration. please read that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port

Comment: @ Jonathana thanks, I will try this out when I get back home later and let you know.

Comment: @Jonathana tried configuring server properties, but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a troubleshooting guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine